# ListView item flashing when scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Please help me this question.
I have a ListView which I declare like that :

```
     <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewContactList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dip"
    android:scrollingCache="false" >
</ListView>
```

And this is the listview item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/contact_list_item_normal_bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dip" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingPart"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_list_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_list_size" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/contact_default_ic" >
    </ProgressBar>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_list_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_list_size"
        android:background="@drawable/image_rounded_coner_bg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:src="@drawable/contact_default_ic" />
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/li1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/loadingPart"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/draft_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewGroupName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/draft_text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description"
    android:src="@drawable/contact_list_item_imail_ic" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I have an Progress bar appear when the imageViewIcon is loading.
And the problem is when the progress bar is showing, if I scroll the listview the listview items will slashing. It only happen if I set the item background to this image

[image]

Thank you very much for any help to fix the problem.

Note : if the item background is white , it work fine. Or If I set the progress bar to invisible it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell without looking at code, but it sounds like the progress bar isn't being loaded in the background. Have a look at ASync Task  where you can kick off the progress bar in the background on another thread.

Comment: I only show the progressbar. And disable it when the image is loaded from a background thread. I did not update anything to progress bar.